# How to guarantee the existence of continuity sets?

Tags: probability-theory, continuity, weak-convergence, coupling

The **Skorohod's representation theorem** says:

*Let $X, X_1, X_2,...$ be S-valued random
elements, where (S, p) is a separable metric space, such that $X_n \xrightarrow{d} X$. Then there exists a common probability space with some random elements $Y, Y_1, Y_2,...$ defined on it such that $Y_n = X_n$ in distribution $\forall n$ and $Y = X$ in distribution, and $Y_n$ converges almost surely to $Y$.*

Every proof I found involves the process of the following construction: for all $x \in S$, for any $\epsilon>0$, one can always pick $r$ with $0<r<\epsilon$ such that $P(X\in \partial B(x,r))=0$.

**My question might be stupid**: why is it always possible to pick such an open ball such that its boundary has measure $0$ in $P_X$? (in other words, an **$X$-continuity** set, which is defined as: a set $A\in B(S)$ such that $P(X\in \partial A)=0$)

For complete proof, see resource: Kallenberg's Foundations of Modern Probability (2002) p79; or Billingsley's Convergence of Probability measures (1999) p70.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\partial B(x,r)\subset \{y: d(y,x)=r\}$. It is obvious from this that $\partial B(x,r), 0<r<\epsilon$ is a disjoint collection of measurable sets. In a probability space you can only have countably many disjoint sets with positive measure. [If you have not seen this before I will add  a proof]. If $P(\partial B(x,r))>0$ whenever $0<r<\epsilon$ you will uncountably many sets with positive measure, a contradiction. Hence, $P(\partial B(x,r))=0$ for some $r \in (0,\epsilon)$.

Proof of $\partial B(x,r)\subset \{y: d(y,x)=r\}$: Let $y \in \partial B(x,r)$. By definition of boundary there exist sequence $(y_n)$ and $(z_n)$ such that $d(y_n,x) <r, d(z_n,x) \geq r$ and $y_n \to y, z_n \to  y$. By continuity of the distance function we get $d(y,x) \leq r $ and $d(y,x) \geq r$ so we must have $d(y,x)=r$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I have actually considered this before, but there is one technicality point I cannot address.

This argument is based on the assumption that there are uncountably many disjoint $\partial B(x,r)$ for $r \in (0, \epsilon)$, but since the Skorohod theorem is based on any metric space, this means $\partial B(x,r)$ may overlap for different $r\in (0, \epsilon)$ (e.g. be the same nonempty set).

Comment: @NanxiangWang What is that technical point?

Comment: Just an example to illustrate that $\partial B(x,r)$ don't need to be disjoint for every different $r\in (0, \epsilon)$:

Let $S=  \{ (0, 1+ 0.5^n): n\in N \} \cup $Solid_Unit_Ball_In_$R^2$ (so just a solid ball with a trailing tail) be the set forming the metric space (with a usual Euclidean metric). Then $\partial B(0,1)=\partial B(0,1.5)=\{ (x,y): x^2+y^2=1\}$.


I know in this case it's fine because there are still uncountably many disjoint $\partial B(x,r)$, but I don't know how to argue in general.

Comment: @NXWang Do you agree that $\partial B(x,r)\subset \{y: d(y,x)=r\}$ and that $\{y: d(y,x)=r\}\cap \{y: d(y,x)=s\}=\emptyset$ for $r \neq s$. I cannot make sense out of your example because your $S$ is not one set but a collection of sets.

Comment: Sorry there's a typo at the end, what I meant by $\partial B(0,1)$ etc. is actually $\partial B((0,0), 1)$ (each element is a 2-d coordinate).

My $S$ is just one set with coordinates in $R^2$, it's the union of the solid unit ball and a trailing tail. It's actually a counterexample of $\partial B(x,r)\subset \{y: d(y,x)=r\}$, because $\partial B((0,0), 1.5) = \{ (x,y)\in S \subset R^2: d((x,y), (0,0))=1 \}$, whereas $\{ (x,y)\in S \subset R^2: d((x,y), (0,0))=1.5\}=\emptyset$

Comment: Don't waste time with your example. I have given a clear proof of the inclusion. Please try to read the proof and let me know if you need more details.  @NXWang

Comment: I realized what I got wrong there. Thanks very much for your proof!